# How to invoke specific execution

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-invoker-plugin

I am trying to replace maven exec with MavenInvokerPlugin because of problems on Jenkins with forwarding the maven settings file.

So in bash it looks straight:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies@resolve-maven-deps
```

My translation to MavenInvokerPlugin configuration is

```
             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectsDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/docker</projectsDirectory>
                    <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.mavenDependencies}</localRepositoryPath>
                    <goal>dependency:copy-dependencies@resolve-maven-deps</goal>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>                                 
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It looks like that execution id is completely ignored, because I tried random strings and mvn builds the project with success.

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies@asdfasdfa
```

So I'd like to know whether this feature is supported at all and what I am doing wrong.

P.S. I know that calling maven out of maven is anti pattern, but here is exactly that rare case when there is no other way.

Comment: In Jenkins you can do things like `withMaven(...) {...}` ?

Comment: jenkins way is not applicable, because the same pom is executed locally

Comment: Hm...Why? The pom is intended for buidling ? What is the real problem here?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at projects using maven invoker I figured out the trick.

goal tag is not used, instead provide invokerPropertiesFile:

```
<pom>${project.basedir}/xxx/pom.xml</pom>    
<invokerPropertiesFile>${project.basedir}/invoker.properties</invokerPropertiesFile>
```

content of the file:

```
invoker.goals=compile -P resolve-maven-deps
```